# Cannot convert Future<String> to String and use in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I try to implement Firebase authentication in my mobile app. (I am very new to this..)

I have the following code which attempts to create the user for the first time:

```
class WpAuthService {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<WpUser> get wpUser {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map((User firebaseUser) =>
        (firebaseUser != null) ? WpUser(uid: firebaseUser.uid) : null);
  }

  Future<String> createUserWithEmail(email, password) async {
    UserCredential userCredential;
    try {
      userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.code + " - " + e.message);
      return e.message;
    }

    return 'SUCCESS';
  }
}
```

And in another file, I am trying to call the `createUserWithEmail` function as following:

```
class SignupForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupFormState createState() => _SignupFormState();
}

class _SignupFormState extends State<SignupForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _userEmail = "";
  var _userPassword = "";

  String _opResult;

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      WpAuthService()
          .createUserWithEmail(_userEmail, _userPassword)
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _opResult = value;
        });
      });

      print('MESSAGE:');
      print(_opResult);
      if (_opResult != 'SUCCESS') {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(_opResult),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email address'),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be at least 7 characters long.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Sign up',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                    onPressed: _trySubmit,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the above piece of code, it prints out the following:

```
I/flutter ( 4032): MESSAGE:
I/flutter ( 4032): null

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

Looking at some other examples, I expect my implementation to work but something is seemingly wrong. How can I use the return value as String from the `createUserWithEmail` function?

Comment: Does initializing  `String _opResult = "";` help?

Comment: @JoyTerence, please see my answer below. My primary problem was not able to set the return value to the _opResult variable. The initial value of _opResult was seemingly not the problem actually.. Your comments are more than welcome.

Comment: did you face this issue only when exception was thrown or was it even in the case of "SUCCESS"?

Comment: Just an add on, an alternate solution could have been to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Before updating the code as in my answer, I was experiencing the problem in both cases, whatever was being returned from the function (success or error).

Comment: @JoyTerence, any chance you can provide that solution in code? As I am new to many of those concepts, it takes ages to make progress in each step.

Comment: The reason why I asked is, I'm not really sure why `then` did not give the value as expected, at least, in case of just `return 'SUCCESS'`. So had suspicion on the exception part.

Comment: No matter it returned an error or not, it returned plain String. If I printed out what was being returned from the function, I could see reasonable values. But I was not able to set the return value to another String variable. Returning Future<String> made the trick. But I do not know why because I saw in some other examples that people were returning plain String values from their functions. (I don't know though if their (pseudo code) was really working..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In the `createUserWithEmail` function, I was returning String values as the following:

```
return e.message;
return 'SUCCESS';
```

I updated it so that the function now returns as stated below:

```
return Future.value(e.message);
return Future.value('SUCCESS');
```

Everything else is the same and it worked.

But I saw some other examples where people were just returning String values from their functions. My problem is solved but is this behavior really expected? You are more than welcome to educate me.

Answer (score 2):

by default your `_opResult` variable is `null` and your passing it to the `Text` widget of the Snackbar which throws that assertion.
You need either to first wait for the response to return or change your code to be inside the `then` method.

```
void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      WpAuthService()
          .createUserWithEmail(_userEmail, _userPassword)
          .then((value) {

        setState(() {
          _opResult = value;
        });

        print('MESSAGE:');
        print(_opResult);
        if (_opResult != 'SUCCESS') {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(_opResult),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
            ),
          );
        }
      });

    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Beside the solution I wrote separately, I also changed the code and made the _trySubmit function async by also putting await in fron of my WpAuthService().createUserWithEmail function call. In this way, I make sure that I wait for the response, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your _opResult is null. And it is not equal to 'SUCCESS'. And you are trying to set it into Text() widget. Text widget requires a string parameter, not null.

You can set a default string when initializing the _opResult. Like this:

```
  String _opResult = "";


  print('MESSAGE:');
  print(_opResult);
  if (_opResult != 'SUCCESS') {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(_opResult),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      ),
    );
  }
```